# Why is my overlay not shown (Android)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently developing an android app. I want to show a map (based on Google Maps) and with pressing a button an overlay should be shown.

So far the map is shown and the overlay is shown, too. BUT: The problem is that the overlay is shown if I press the button twice although the overlay should be invisible after pressing the button a second time. I tried to swap the view.setVisisiblity(View.VISISBLE) and the view.setVisisiblity(View.INVISIBLE) call but the result was almost the same...I used a TextureView to solve this problem.

```
    public void openWindowOnButtonClick() {
    view = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    FloatingActionButton fb = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    final InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getBaseContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // check if the Overlay should be visible. If this value is true, it is not shown -> show it.
            if (view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.bringToFront();
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my method to swap the overlay's status from visible to invisible and the other way around.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can u add some print?

Answer (score 0):

TextureView will not be available unless initializing SurfaceTexture , i don't know why textureview is available after the first click ,but you can use SurfaceView, or you can  use TextureView With setting SurfaceTexture

```
public void openWindowOnButtonClick() {
    view = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    view.setSurfaceTexture(new SurfaceTexture(GLES20.GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE));
    view.getSurfaceTexture().detachFromGLContext();
    FloatingActionButton fb = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    final InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getBaseContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // check if the Overlay should be visible. If this value is true, it is not shown -> show it.
            if (view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.bringToFront();
                view.getParent().requestLayout();
                ((View)view.getParent()).invalidate();
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but it will log error in monitor but will work with you

Comment: Kindly See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

Comment: Thank you guys, 

I will try it Ahmed Aboelyazeed

If it does not work, I will give you some print (@Bruno Pinto).